# log4j prints all levels

Tags: java, log4j

I've got log4j configured on my Java project with the following log4j.properties:

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARNING, X

log4j.appender.X=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.X.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.X.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %m %n

log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=WARNING
log4j.logger.com.****.services.clarity.dao.impl=WARNING
log4j.logger.com.****.services.clarity.controller=WARNING
log4j.logger.com.****.services.clarity.services.impl=WARNING
log4j.logger.com.****.services.clarity.feeds.impl=WARNING
```

As configured, it should only print WARNING messages, however it prints all levels to DEBUG.

any ideas where this can come from ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The log level should be "WARN" and not "WARNING"

Answer (score 10):

Isnt the severity level called "WARN"?

Answer (score 0):

It is true that the log level should be `WARN`, but this still won't prevent the root logger from displaying the `DEBUG` messages.

I've learned two ways to suppress those `DEBUG` messages.  See my [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023690/why-is-log4j-rootlogger-not-filtering-log-events-according-to-event-level/3024279#3024279) to a practically identical [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023690/why-is-log4j-rootlogger-not-filtering-log-events-according-to-event-level/3024279) which I derived from two different answers to a similar question.