# Why is Log4j rootLogger not filtering log events according to event level?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Why is the [Log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/) `rootLogger` in my application not filtering log events according to level?  In my `log4j.properties`, I have several loggers:

```
log4j.rootLogger=info,stdout
log4j.logger.com.name.myapp=debug,myapp
log4j.logger.org.castor=debug,castor
log4j.logger.org.exolab.castor=debug,castor
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=debug,hibernate
log4j.logger.org.springframework=debug,spring
```

Each of the loggers receive and record numerous log events at levels `DEBUG` and above, which is what I expect and desire.  The `rootLogger`, however, despite being set to level `INFO`, is displaying all of these events, too, including the `DEBUG` events, which is not what I expect and not what I desire.  Instead, I would expect it to filter the `DEBUG` events, but display only the events at level `INFO` and higher (`WARN`, `ERROR`, and `FATAL`), which is also what I want.  Why is rootLogger displaying all of the events?

Comment: you have provided the level as debug for com.name.myapp,org.castor,org.hibernate,org.springframework so for these pkgs it will print debug information right?

Comment: Yes, these levels print debug events.  However, the rootLogger prints all the events, but I want it to print just info events.

Comment: then change the level to info.

Comment: The threshold level of root logger is already set to `INFO`.  That's my point.  Root logger is accepting the debug events, too.  Why?

Comment: As I discuss in my answer below, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453010/log4j-rootlogger-seems-to-inherit-log-level-of-other-logger-why/2453554#2453554 explains why root logger captures the events of all other loggers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453010/log4j-rootlogger-seems-to-inherit-log-level-of-other-logger-why/2453554#2453554) to a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453010/log4j-rootlogger-seems-to-inherit-log-level-of-other-logger-why) about logger chaining in Log4j:

> The way Log4j chaining works is a bit
>   counter intuitive (to me at least). If
>   the request level is equal to or above
>   the threshold of the most specific
>   matching logger, it is accepted. Once
>   the request is accepted, it gets
>   handled by the complete chain of
>   ancestors regardless of their
>   thresholds!

This means that no matter to what level you set the threshold of the root logger, it will always accept and output the log event that any other logger accepts, unless you disable chaining for that child logger or explicitly set the threshold of its appender to a higher level.

So, in this case, there are two ways that you can prevent root logger from capturing the events from the other loggers.  The first is the more selective approach of disabling log event chaining:

```
log4j.additivity.com.name.myapp=false
log4j.additivity.org.castor=false
log4j.additivity.org.exolab.castor=false
log4j.additivity.org.hibernate=false
log4j.additivity.org.springframework=false
```

The second way is simpler, but more restrictive since it suppresses all events on the console that are lower than `INFO` (`DEBUG` and `TRACE`):

```
log4j.appender.stdout.Threshold=info
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out the inheritance described in the [intro](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html).  If you specify a level at the package level, it won't inherit the root logger's level.  You're using debug in the packages you specify, not info.  Specifying the level overrides whatever has been inherited.

If you want to inherit the root logger's level, get rid of the level specification in your logger configurations.

Comment: I don't want the packages to inherit the root logger level.  I want the root logger to omit debug events and display only info and above to the console.

Comment: @Derek Mahar check out http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html.  Use %c to see what your levels are really doing.  You should be able to track down what's going on better this way.

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve the rootlogger, are you using `Logger.getRootLogger()`? If not, you may not be getting the real root logger. If so, make sure the Threshold of `stdout` isnt at debug; the Threshold of appenders override that of the logger Levels.

Comment: What is the default priority level of an appender?  Is it `ALL`?

Comment: Sorry, I meant <code>Threshold</code>. The answer you found below was correct.

Comment: Your answer is on the right track, but as I mention in my answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023690/why-is-log4j-rootlogger-not-filtering-log-events-according-to-event-level/3024279#3024279), one of two possible solutions was to set the threshold of appender `stdout` to `INFO`.